# How to get animation to work at exact points during playback of a music file?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

> **Question:**
>
> In Swift code, apart from using an `NSTimer`, how can I get animations
>   to start at exact points during playback of a music file played using `AVFoundation`?

---

**Background**

I have a method that plays a music file using `AVFoundation` (below). I also have UIView animations that I want to start at exact points during the music file being played.

One way I could achieve this is using an `NSTimer`, but that has the potential to get out of sync or not be exact enough.

**Is there a method that I can tap into `AVFoundation` accessing the music file's time elapsed (time counter), so when certain points during the music playback arrive, animations start?**

**Is there an event / notification that `AVFoundation` triggers that gives a constant stream of time elapsed since the music file has started playing?**

---

***For example***

At 0:52.50 (52 seconds and 1/2), call `startAnimation1()`, at 1:20.75 (1 minute, 20 seconds and 3/4), call `startAnimation2()`, and so on?

```
switch musicPlayingTimeElapsed {

case 0:52.50:
     startAnimation1()

case 1:20.75:
     startAnimation2()

default:
     ()

}
```

---

**Playing music using `AVFoundation`**

```
import AVFoundation
var myMusic : AVAudioPlayer?

func playMusic() {
    if let musicFile = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("fileName", type:"mp3") {
        self.myMusic = musicFile
    }
    myMusic?.play()
}

func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer?  {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudioPlayer not available")
    }
    return audioPlayer
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `AVPlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer`, you can use the (TBH slightly awkward) `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes` method:

```
let times = [
    NSValue(CMTime:CMTimeMake(...)),
    NSValue(CMTime:CMTimeMake(...)),
    NSValue(CMTime:CMTimeMake(...)),
    // etc
];

var observer: AnyObject? = nil   // instance variable

self.observer = self.player.addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes(times, queue: nil) {
    switch self.player.currentTime() {
    case 0:52.50:
        startAnimation1()
    case 1:20.75:
        startAnimation2()
    default:
        break
    }
}


// call this to stop observer   
self.player.removeTimeObserver(self.observer)
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I solve this is to divide the music up into separate segments beforehand. I then use one of two approaches:

- I play the segments one at a time, each in its own audio player. The audio player's delegate is notified when a segment finishes, and so starting the next segment — along with accompanying action — is up to me.
- Alternatively, I queue up all the segments onto an AVQueuePlayer. I then use KVO on the queue player's `currentItem`. Thus, I am notified *exactly* when we move to a new segment.

Comment: Interesting. There's no noticeable gaps in playback of a segmented audio, it just plays smoothly?

Comment: If you use AVQueuePlayer there will be no gaps. That is what an AVQueuePlayer _is_.

Comment: Thanks for that description.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Key Value Observing to observe the duration property of your sound as it plays. When the duration reaches your time thresholds you'd trigger each animation. You'd need to make the time thresholds match times >= the trigger time, since you will likely not get a perfect match with your desired time.

I don't know how well that would work however. First, I'm not sure if the sound player's duration is KVO-compliant.

Next, KVO is somewhat resource-intensive, and if your KVO listener gets called thousands of times a second it might bog things down. It would at least be worth a try.